Room Database IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify data integrity after schema change
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
fun providesLocalDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): TaskDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, TaskDatabase::class.java, "task_db")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()


This solved the problem. It makes sure that database is created only once.
companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var Instance: TaskDatabase? = null

        fun providesLocalDatabase(context: Context): TaskDatabase {
            // if the Instance is not null, return it, otherwise create a new database instance.
            return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, TaskDatabase::class.java, "task_db")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                    .also { Instance = it }
            }
        }
    }

